# ConstraintLayout doesn't update size sometimes; shows error "no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-constraintlayout

I have a Xamarin.Android app that shows lyrics from Genius and can detect music playing from the notifications.

In this app, the Main Activity contains a FrameLayout that is dynamically filled with a Welcome screen layout or a Song layout. The first is used when the user opens the app and no song has been detected, while the second appears when the user searches a song or opens the app through the notification sent when the app finds a song playing. Both the Welcome layout and the Song layout use ConstraintLayouts to display content.

This is how the layout looks without content:
[image: This is how the layout looks without content]

Sometimes while loading the song, the layout size is not updated to fit the content inside the views. It has a loading wheel that is set to Gone when the lyrics finish loading.

Fully loaded, the screen should look like this:

[image: Complete layout]

However, it looks like this:

[image: Broken layout]

You can see that the broken layout is the same size and shape as it is on Android Studio.

The only thing I've been able to correlate with this bug is this LogCat message:

```
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@2bd3336
```

This message always appears when this bug happens, but not the other way around. Sometimes it appears but the bug does not happen.

From what I've googled, this is related to the notification opening another instance of the MainActivity. My testing suggests this as well since the OnCreate method is called even when the app is already opened and the notification is touched. I have not been able to get this bug to occur without opening the app through the notification.

Here's the code that created the notification:

```cs
private void CreateNotification(string title, string artist)
{
    Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Verbose, "NLService", "CreateNotification: Creating notification");
    MainActivity.fromNotification = true;

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(Application.Context);
    stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)));
    stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));

    PendingIntent resultIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .SetAutoCancel(true)
        .SetContentTitle("SmartLyrics")
        .SetContentText(artist + " - " + title)
        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_name)
        .SetContentIntent(resultIntent)
        .SetPriority(-1);

    ntfManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
    ntfManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.Build());
    Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Info, "NLService", "CreateNotification (NLService): Notification made!");
}
```

I [recorded my phone screen](https://gfycat.com/acceptablefavoritecod) showing how it's behaving, first opening from the notification and then closing the app and opening the Song by searching from inside the app. [Here's the LogCat](https://pastebin.com/nWAVAX01) for that session.

The whole project is open source, and the code is available [here](https://github.com/AndroidWG/SmartLyrics/tree/layout-testing) (the `layout-testing` branch is the one you should be looking at). Please spare me on how much this code is bad, I know about it and I'm slowly fixing stuff. This issue has been plaguing me for a long time and I want to get it fixed before working on other things.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to add the `LancuhMode =`SingleTop` or `SingleTask` to your Activity,and overwrite `OnNewIntent` method and do something you want in it.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I already had `LaunchMode = SingleTask`, however did not override `OnNewIntent`. I added the override but `OnNewIntent` wasn't called at all and the problem persisted. I tried using `SingleTop` instead and got the same results. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try to add   ` intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);` `intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);` in your CreateNotification method when you want to open MainActivity.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I added the flags like this: https://pastebin.com/ayXggRS2
This didn't solve the problem. I've tried creating a new project to debug this using the same notification code and layout as my main project. The `no activity for token` message still appears and `OnNewIntent` is not called, however the ConstraintLayout works correctly. 
I'm currently trying to see if this is a problem related to bad/outdaded/conflicting NuGet packages.

Comment: Yes,you could have a try.